# Plot arc path between two points

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

I am trying to plot a curved path for a robot to follow using the following as a guide:  http://rossum.sourceforge.net/papers/CalculationsForRobotics/CirclePath.htm

The code i have does not create a path that ends at the destination. I am expecting the path to curve left or right depending on the quadrant the destination is in (+x+y,+x-y,-x+y,-x-y)

```
import math
start = [400,500]
dest = [200,300]
speed = 10
startangle = 0
rc =0
rotv =0
rads =0

def getPos(t):
    ang = (rotv*t)+rads
    x = start[0] - rc * math.sin(rads) + rc * math.sin(rotv*(t)+rads)
    y = start[1] + rc * math.cos(rads) - rc * math.cos(rotv*(t)+rads)
    return (int(x),int(y), ang)

dx = dest[0] - start[0]
dy = dest[1] - start[1]
rads = math.atan2(-dy,dx)
rads %= 2*math.pi
distance = (dx**2 + dy**2)**.5  #rg
bangle = 2*rads
rc = distance /(2 * math.sin(rads))
if rads > (math.pi/2):
    bangle = 2*(rads-math.pi)
    rc= -rc
if rads < -(math.pi/2):
    bangle = 2*(rads+math.pi)
    rc= -rc
pathlength = rc * bangle
xc = start[0] - rc * math.sin(rads)
yc = start[1] + rc * math.cos(rads)
rotcenter = [xc,yc]
traveltime = pathlength/speed
rotv = bangle/traveltime
for p in range(int(traveltime)):
    pos = getPos(p)
```

Start: Blue, End: Red, Rotation Point: Purple
[image]

UPDATE: 
I have added code to allow positive and negative x/y values. I have updated the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question I first read through the article you linked. I think it is very interesting and explains the ideas behind the formulas pretty well, althought it lacks the formulas for when the starting position is not at the origin and when the starting angle is not 0.

It took a little while to come up with these formulas, but now it works for every case I could think of. To be able to use the formulas given in the linked article, I used the names of the variables given there. Notice that I also used the notation with `t_0` as the starting time, which you just ignored. You can easily remove any instance of `t_0` or set `t_0 = 0`.

The last part of the following code is used for testing and creates a little red turtle that traces the path of the computed arc in the specified direction. The black turtle indicates the goal position. Both turtles are close to each other at the end of the animation, but they are not directly above each other, because I am only iterating over integers and it is possible that t_1 is not an integer.

```
from math import pi, hypot, sin, cos, atan2, degrees

def norm_angle(a):
    # Normalize the angle to be between -pi and pi
    return (a+pi)%(2*pi) - pi

# Given values
# named just like in http://rossum.sourceforge.net/papers/CalculationsForRobotics/CirclePath.htm
x_0, y_0 = [400,500] # initial position of robot
theta_0 = -pi/2      # initial orientation of robot
s = 10               # speed of robot
x_1, y_1 = [200,300] # goal position of robot
t_0 = 0              # starting time

# To be computed:
r_G = hypot(x_1 - x_0, y_1 - y_0)        # relative polar coordinates of the goal
phi_G = atan2(y_1 - y_0, x_1 - x_0)
phi = 2*norm_angle(phi_G - theta_0)      # angle and 
r_C = r_G/(2*sin(phi_G - theta_0))       # radius (sometimes negative) of the arc
L = r_C*phi                              # length of the arc
if phi > pi:
    phi -= 2*pi
    L = -r_C*phi
elif phi < -pi:
    phi += 2*pi
    L = -r_C*phi
t_1 = L/s + t_0                        # time at which the robot finishes the arc
omega = phi/(t_1 - t_0)                # angular velocity           
x_C = x_0 - r_C*sin(theta_0)           # center of rotation
y_C = y_0 + r_C*cos(theta_0)

def position(t):
    x = x_C + r_C*sin(omega*(t - t_0) + theta_0)
    y = y_C - r_C*cos(omega*(t - t_0) + theta_0)
    return x, y

def orientation(t):
    return omega*(t - t_0) + theta_0

#--------------------------------------------
# Just used for debugging
#--------------------------------------------
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, 600, 600)

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape("turtle")
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(x_1, y_1)
turtle.setheading(degrees(orientation(t_1)))
turtle.stamp()
turtle.goto(x_0, y_0)
turtle.color("red")
turtle.showturtle()
turtle.pendown()
for t in range(t_0, int(t_1)+1):
    turtle.goto(*position(t))
    turtle.setheading(degrees(orientation(t)))
```

I am not sure at which point your code failed, but I hope this works for you. If you intend to use this snippet multiple times in you code consider encapsulating it in a function that takes in the given values as parameters and returns the `position` function (and if you like `rotation` function as well).